# Summing values then adding to table and keep summing? PHP

Tags: php, html

Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is this: 
I have a page that asks for

1. Principal Amount
2. Interest Amount
3. year variable

What I'm having trouble with is the Principal and Interest Amount.

When the user hits submit, it creates a table based on the year variable. Example,

> If the year variable is == to 10 then the tables has 10 rows. 
>   Then the 2nd column will have the principal amount that the user entered, and the 3rd will have the interest rate the user entered.

But my problem is, the table displays the same information over and over for all rows.

I need to have the second, third, fourth, etc row to display the principal amount+Interest amount.

```
<?php
$_SESSION['intRateSession'] = $intRate;
$_SESSION['totalAmountSession'] = $prinAmount*$intRate;

// Checks if submit is pressed, if so, grabs the $ytd variable to see how many
// times it loops (To create the amount of table rows);
if  (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $ytd; ++$i)
    {
        // Print out the amount of table rows based on the amount of years;
?>
        <tr>
          <th> <?php echo "Year " .$i; ?> </th>

          <!-- *** Info to go in the principal amount at year start row *** -->
          <!-- *** Trying to figure this out still *** -->
          <th><?php echo $_SESSION['totalAmountSession']; ?></th>

          <!-- *** Info to go in the interest row *** -->
          <!-- *** Trying to figure this out still *** -->
          <th><?php echo $_SESSION['intRateSession']; ?></th>
        </tr>
<?php
    }
}
?>
</table>
```

The second row should display the sum of the principal amount and interest amount from the previous row all the way until the bottom.

Comment: Where is `$prinAmount` coming from?

Comment: Build all the info in a 2-dimensional array, *then* feed that array into the code to display it. In general, mixing the calculations [business logic] with the display logic makes your code confusing and difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$amounts = array();
$startAmount = 1000000; // not given in your code?
for ($i = 0; $i < $ytd; ++$i)
{
  $startAmount = $startAmount * $interestRate + $startAmount;
  $amounts[] = array( "year" => $i+1,
                      "amount" => $startAmount,
                      "interest" => $interestRate
  };
}

foreach ( $amounts as $amount )
{
?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $amount['year']; ?>
  <td><?php echo $amount['interest']; ?>
  <td><?php echo $amount['amount']; ?>
</tr>
<?php
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, I just had to change the formula around for $startAmount but that was all really. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help with this little snippet of code. Next time try going full circle showing every part of the code that is involved in the issue. For example: where is `$prinAmount` variable declared?
From my perspective your variables' declarations are static, it is expected they show the same information over and over since they are not changing.
Try moving `$_SESSION['totalAmountSession']` declaration **inside** the FOR loop incremeting itself each iteration. Something like:
`$_SESSION['totalAmountSession']=$_SESSION['totalAmountSession']+($prinAmount*$intRate);`
Be sure you are working with numbers. Good luck!